# How to get first only first 2 digits using Regular expression

Tags: html, regex, parsing, jmeter

I am using JMeter and trying to write a Regular expression (regex) that can return the two digit class ID from some HTML option elements.

```
<option value="53">1ABC Class</option>
<option value="52">2XYZ Class</option>
<option value="69" selected="selected">001 Class</option>
```

using following regex..

```
value="..">1ABC Class<
```

returns

```
value="53">1ABC Class<
```

In the example given, the only return values I want are `53`, `52` and `69`.

I am looking for a regex that will work with all of above given options.

Comment: What is the regex flavor/programming language/tool? Is it for JMeter?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, XML, or other mark-up languages. Parsers are much more reliable than any regex that you may construct.

Comment: If you can use the Xpath Extractor (and I think you can), the xpath will be `//option[text() = '1ABC Class']/@value` to get `53`, or `//option/@value` to get the `values` of `option` nodes.

Comment: Yes, wiktor it is for JMeter and I am checking it with https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
value="(\d+)".*?>1ABC Class<
```

This will give the result in the brackets as the needed value only, plus it would match any tag.

Answer (score 3):

[Never use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748). Each time you use regular expressions to parse HTML somewhere somehow a kitten dies.

Go for [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)

[image: JMeter CSS Jquery Extractor]

Go for [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

[image: JMeter XPath Extractor]

But do me a favour, don't use regular expressions for HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Even though moustafa solution worked but I went with xpath extractor as suggested by wiktor. Will try CSS extractor later as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not Regex solution for `c#` or `vb.net`

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(yourXmltext);
var options = doc.Root.Descendants("option");

foreach(var option in options)
{
    var value = option.Attribute("value").Value;
    var className = option.Value;
}
```

[LINQ to Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx) makes code little bid more readable

Comment: If it is for JMeter, this C# code will be of no use.